# If/then on Increment Slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

Is it possible to create an if/then statement on a increment slider?
Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 2,
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="amount">
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">

</p>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

In other words, I have a slider with 3 increments. When the increment is at min- I'd like it to display a div (with content) and at med and max two other divs.

I figure the best way is to do an if/then, but not exactly sure how to go about it.

Solution?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Slider - Snap to increments</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>

</style>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 2,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
        },

        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.value == 0) {
                $("#stepone").show();

            } 
             else if(ui.value == 1) {
                $("#stepone").hide();
                $("#steptwo").show();
                $("#stepthree").hide();            } 
            else {
                $("#stepone").hide();
                $("#steptwo").hide();
                $("#stepthree").show();            }
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider").slider("value"));

});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="stepone">Step One</div>

<div id="steptwo">Step Two</div>

<div id="stepthree">Step 3</div>
<input style="display:none"type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`change`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) event:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:0,
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
    },
    change: function( event, ui) {
        if (ui.value == 0) {
            $("#mindiv").show();
        } else {
            $("#mindiv").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/STryh/2/)

Comment: thanks for taking the time. Still alittle confused. I can't get it to work. Any chance you can show me on jsfiddle?

Comment: I've added more details to the answer, does that help?

Comment: Check for Javascript errors. Can you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: not sure if the change functions goes in the body and the other piece goes in the head sections?

Comment: It all just goes into this one call.

Comment: I've fixed your fiddle. You put the `change` stuff outside the options argument, that's not even valid JS syntax.

Comment: thanks Barmar! One last thing, the hide and how is not working on the change... the slider works and the increments change, but nothing happens as far as hide and show!

Comment: weird, on my the slider does work and increments the value, but the #mindiv is always visible...

Comment: Then you haven't copied it correctly into your code.

Comment: Add an update to your question, showing the current version of the code.

Comment: haha, ok, I got it working now.. I clicked the scrollbar to the area and it seem to work, thanks so much... how much do I owe you? :)

Comment: have updated question with current code, one last issue, the slider shows all divs even though it's set to value 0

Comment: When `ui.value == 0` you show `#stepone`, but you don't hide `#steptwo` and `#stepthree`. Also, you should use CSS to hide steps two and three initially. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/STryh/4/

Comment: gotcha, I did hide() on .ready... seemed exessive. I tried visibility but that did not work. Thanks Barmar, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `change` event

```
$( "#slider" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
  var value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
  if(value==1){
  }else{
  }
});
```

Comment: It's better to use `ui.value` since you already have the object.